# How to handle reference counting when returning numpy array aliasing internal array?

Tags: python, numpy, boost-python

I've got a class called ctcorrgen that's doing some numeric processing, and returns a row of results at a time through a const pointer to an internal array.  I'd like to wrap this internal array into a read-only Numpy array and return it, like this:

```
static inline PyObject* ctcorrgen_yield_row(object &object) {
    // extract corrgen base
    ctcorrgen &corrgen = extract<ctcorrgen&>(object);

    // get row of data
    const cfloat* row = corrgen.yield_row();
    if (row == nullptr) {
        return detail::none();        
    } else {
        // build read-only array around data
        npy_intp len = corrgen.framesize();
        return PyArray_New(
            &PyArray_Type, 1, &len, NPY_COMPLEX64, NULL, (void*)row, 0,
            NPY_ARRAY_C_CONTIGUOUS | NPY_ARRAY_ALIGNED, NULL
        );
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I set things up so that the new array object references the object it was created from, so that it won't get garbage collected before we're done with the array (thus destroying the underlying buffer)?  I'm using boost::python but I suspect this requires more knowledge of the Python C-API directly than I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I found the answer, for anyone that comes after me.

Looking at the definition for PyArrayObject:

```
typedef struct PyArrayObject {
    PyObject_HEAD
    char *data;
    int nd;
    npy_intp *dimensions;
    npy_intp *strides;
    PyObject *base;
    PyArray_Descr *descr;
    int flags;
    PyObject *weakreflist;
} PyArrayObject;
```

The key is the [base pointer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject.base):

> PyObject *PyArrayObject.base
>
> This member is used to hold a pointer to
>   another Python object that is related to this array. There are two use
>   cases: 1) If this array does not own its own memory, then base points
>   to the Python object that owns it (perhaps another array object), 2)
>   If this array has the (deprecated) NPY_ARRAY_UPDATEIFCOPY or
>   :c:data:NPY_ARRAY_WRITEBACKIFCOPY`: flag set, then this array is a
>   working copy of a “misbehaved” array. When
>   PyArray_ResolveWritebackIfCopy is called, the array pointed to by base
>   will be updated with the contents of this array.

Combined with this paragraph from PyArray_New:

> Warning
>
> If data is passed to PyArray_NewFromDescr or PyArray_New, this
>   memory must not be deallocated until the new array is deleted. If this
>   data came from another Python object, this can be accomplished using
>   Py_INCREF on that object and setting the base member of the new array
>   to point to that object. If strides are passed in they must be
>   consistent with the dimensions, the itemsize, and the data of the
>   array.

So, I believe something like this is the appropriate way to establish the required relationship (for Numpy >= 1.7)

```
// increment reference to ctcorrgen object and set base pointer
// of array, this will establish an ownership link so that
// ctcorrgen won't be destroyed before the array.
incref(object.ptr());
PyArray_SetBaseObject((PyArrayObject*)array, object.ptr());
```